# limit EntityRecognitionSkill to confident > .5

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cognitive-search, named-entity-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsoft.Skills.Text.EntityRecognitionSkill in my skillset which output "Person", "Location", "Organization".
however I want to only output Location that have a confident level > .5
is there a way to do that?
here is a snap of my code

```
{
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.EntityRecognitionSkill",
      "categories": [
        "Person",
        "Location",
        "Organization"
      ],
      "context": "/document/finalText/pages/*",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/finalText/pages/*"
        },
        {
          "name": "languageCode",
          "source": "/document/languageCode"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "persons",
          "targetName": "people"
        },
        {
          "name": "locations"
        },
        {
          "name": "namedEntities",
          "targetName": "entities"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Edited based on Mick's comment]

Yes, this should be possible by setting the `minimumPrecision` parameter of the entity recognition skill to 0.5, which will result in entities whose confidence is >= 0.5 to be returned.

The documentation for entity recognition skill is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-entity-recognition

As Mick points out, the documentation says `minimumPrecision` is unused, however that documentation is out of date and I will fix it soon.

Comment: The NamedEntityRecognitionSkill has been deprecated and is replaced with the [EntityRecognitionSkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-entity-recognition). `minimumPrecision` is not available (yet) in the EntityRecognitionSkill and it looks like the precision is not available in the output.

Comment: You are correct in that the NamedEntityRecognitionSkill has been deprecated.
However EntityRecognitionSkill now supports `minimumPrecision`.

I will edit my answer and will make a note to update the documentation

Comment: Thanks Arvind! Good to know :)